# How to lock a parent record in Rails/ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, locking

When there is a single parent record associated with multiple child records, using row locking on the parent record is an obvious way to ensure consistency. However, I cannot seem to find a clean way to do this in ActiveRecord.

---

For example, say we have two models: `Order` and `OrderProduct`.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_products
  ...
end

class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  ...
end
```

Updating an `OrderProduct` affects the overall state of the `Order`, so we want to make sure only one transaction is updating an `Order` at any given time.

If we're trying to achieve this when editing an `OrderProduct`, the cleanest way in ruby I can see is:

```
def edit
  product = OrderProduct.find params[:id]
  Order.transaction do
    product.order.lock!
    # Make sure no changes have occurred while we were waiting for the lock
    product.reload

    # Do stuff...
    product.order.some_method
  end
end
```

However this if rather inefficient with SQL queries, producing:

```
SELECT "order_products".* FROM "order_products" WHERE "order_products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 [["id", "2"]]
SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE  [["id", 2]]
SELECT "order_products".* FROM "order_products" WHERE "order_products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 [["id", 2]]
SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
```

---

We can reduce the number of queries by changing the to something along the lines of:

```
def edit
  product = OrderProduct.find params[:id]
  Order.transaction do
    order = Order.find product.order_id, lock: true
    # Make sure no changes have occurred while we were waiting for the lock
    product.reload
    # Cache the association
    product.order = order

    # Do stuff...
    product.order.some_method
  end
end
```

which produces better SQL:

```
SELECT "order_products".* FROM "order_products" WHERE "order_products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 [["id", "2"]]
SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE  [["id", 2]]
SELECT "order_products".* FROM "order_products" WHERE "order_products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 [["id", 2]]
```

However the code is messier.

**Is there a cleaner way of doing this with ActiveRecord?** Calling `product.order = order` just to get the association cached seems a little dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple Rails way of locking, check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

Comment: I'm aware of the methods mentioned in this documentation, but they don't seems to work very well with associations (see SQL above). I've added some further code examples to question.

Answer (score 0):

```
.lock.load
```

Is what you are looking for.
probably?